# How do I link a record/cells to a chart in Excel? FullSeriesCollection

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I've created a small control panel that automatically copies the entered data, adds a new record to a table and recolors the cells of that record. For insertion, the macro searches for the last empty row of the table and inserts the data there.

Now, I would like to add the same record in a chart in another worksheet by linking it with the record in the table.

Unfortunately, my code doesn't work as expected and I do not know why. Hope you can help me!

```
Sub DatensatzAnlegen()

'Find next clear row
Range("A6:M6").Select
Selection.Copy
CurrentRow = 13
Do Until Range("A" & CurrentRow) = ""
    CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
Loop
Cells(CurrentRow, 1).Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("E9:M9").Select
Selection.Copy
Cells(CurrentRow, 14).Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste

'Recolor cell of the new record
Cells(CurrentRow, 1).Select
    With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
    .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With

'Link data with chart
Sheets("Diagramm").ChartObjects("DiagrammA").Activate
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection.Name = Sheets("Übersicht").Cells(CurrentRow, 1) 'DOES NOT WORK
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection.XValues = Sheets("Übersicht").Cells(CurrentRow, 2) 'DOES NOT WORK
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection.Values = Sheets("Übersicht").Cells(CurrentRow, 3) 'DOES NOT WORK

'Clear control panel
ActiveSheets.Übersicht
Range("A6:M6").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("E9:M9").Select
Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The piece of code below will add the added row with data to your `"DiagrammA"` chart in `"Diagramm"` worksheet.

**Note**: you have way too many unecessary `Select`, `Selection` and `ActiveSheet`. Instead, use fully qualified objects like setting the `ChartObject` :

```
Set ChtObj = Chtws.ChartObjects("DiagrammA")
```

and using `With` statement: `With Dataws`, etc...

Detailed explanations inside the code's comments.

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub DatensatzAnlegen()

Dim CurrentRow As Long
Dim Dataws As Worksheet
Dim Chtws As Worksheet
Dim ChtObj As ChartObject
Dim Ser As Series

' set the worksheet with the data for the chart
Set Dataws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Übersicht")

' set the worksheet where the chart is located
Set Chtws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Diagramm")

With Dataws ' always qualify all your Range and cells objects
    'Find next clear row
    CurrentRow = .Range("A13").End(xlDown).Row + 1
    .Range("A6:M6").Copy Destination:=.Range("A" & CurrentRow)

    ' the same should apply for the block below
   ' .Range("E9:M9").Copy Destination:=.Range("A" & CurrentRow + 1)

    'Recolor cell of the new record
    With .Cells(CurrentRow, 1).Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
        .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End With

' set the chart object
Set ChtObj = Chtws.ChartObjects("DiagrammA")

'Link data with chart
With ChtObj
    Set Ser = .Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries ' add a new series to chart

    With Ser
        .Name = "=" & Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 1).Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)
        .XValues = "=" & Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 2).Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)
        .Values = "=" & Dataws.Cells(CurrentRow, 3).Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)
    End With
End With

' rest of your code 

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply! I think the new problem is now that the data in A14 gets overwritten everytime I try to add a new record to the table. Also .Range("A6:M6").Copy Destination:=.Range("A" & CurrentRow) doesn't work. I get a 1004 runtime error.